# UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName not working

Tags: ios, xcode6, uilocalnotification

I have done with my UILoocalNotification in my iPhon App. I am trying to add sound to my notification message. I tried both default and custom one which I have added in my bundle but both are not working.

i'm using xcode 6.1.1

Here is my code

```
-(void)localNotificaiton{

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
//localNotif.fireDate = date;  // date after 10 sec from now
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Notification details
localNotif.fireDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
localNotif.alertBody =  [[self.allMsgsArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"]; // text of you that you have fetched
// Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

//// localNotif.soundName =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bell" ofType:@"wav"];

```
// Specify custom data for the notification
//NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];

NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[infoDict setObject: [[self.allMsgsArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];


localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification  *)notif {
    // Handle the notificaton when the app is running
    UIApplicationState state = [app applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {



        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New Message: %@" ,notif.alertBody]
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }



    // Set icon badge number to zero

    app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

}
```

I could not hear any thing. the phone volume is full.

and my app received all notification. once it run when ever user change some thing other end my App get notification, both pop up and added to notification centre… but no sound Please guid me where i'm doing mistake :(

Comment: Was your app active (i.e. open) at the time you received the notification?

Comment: its open but in a background @tilo

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I am facing the same issue?